# Assets and CSS not working on Heroku, but work on github pages

Tags: ruby, heroku, jekyll

I have built a website and have until now hosted it on github pages:
https://ge00rg.github.io/website/
Here is the link to the repo in case you want to take a look at the files:
https://github.com/ge00rg/website

Now I want to move it to heroku. The site does deploy, but does not get displayed correctly, as you can see here:
https://hidden-escarpment-98567.herokuapp.com/

It seems like the assets and CSS are somehow not linked correctly, but I can't figure out why.

EDIT: Never mind, found the error. I just needed to configure the _config.yml differently and set

```
baseurl: ""
url: "https://hidden-escarpment-98567.herokuapp.com"
```

Comment: Cool that you found the error! Maybe you could close this question by writing a self-answer and mark your answer. It could also help other!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adjusting the following in _config.yml:

```
baseurl: ""
url: "https://hidden-escarpment-98567.herokuapp.com"
```

so that Jekyll would be able to find main.css and all the assets.